# Prioritise older pipeline runs over newer

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In short, is there a way to sort the Jenkins queue based on build/run age instead of how long it has been in the queue?

Some background, we've got a pipeline script which do several tasks in parallel and then, at the end have a step which aggregates the results from the parallel tasks. Here's a simplified version:

```
stage ('Do Parrallel stuff') {
    def par = [:]
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { par[i] = {sleep(10)} }
    parallel par;
}

stage ('Aggregate') {
    node {
      echo "Aggregating stuff"
    }
}
```

Normally, when there's only one ongoing run this works fine. I.e. it runs the four parallel tasks and then do the aggregate part. However during high load this setup fails. Let's consider the following scenario where we have one Jenkins instance with one executor:

1. We have a job as defined above
2. We start two concurrent runs for this job (with a few seconds in between), run #1 and #2.
3. Immediately we will have 8 sub-tasks in the queue, four tasks for each run, let's call them`#1[1]`, `#1[2]`, `#1[3]`, `#1[4]`, `#2[1]`, `#2[2]`, `#2[3]` and `#2[4]`
4. Jenkins will start executing the first task, `#1[1]`, and we will have seven tasks in the queue.
5. This goes onwards, we execute `#1[2]`, `#1[3]` and `#1[4]`.
6. At this point the pipeline script for `#1` can continue and schedules the aggregate subtask, `#1-Aggr`
7. Next Jenkins will execute `#2[1]`, `#2[2]` and so on
8. Finally `#1-Aggr` and `#2-Aggr` will be executed

This is really problematic since a lot of time can pass in between the job first starting and the aggregate task getting scheduled. All sub tasks for younger runs scheduled in between has to complete before the aggregate subtask is executed. The net result is that we have a lot of ongoing runs and non completing.

**So is there any way to change this behaviour? E.g. sort the queue based on when the run started and not when the task arrived in the queue? Normally (before pipeline) this wasn't a problem since those two metrics were the same, however this is not true for pipelines.**

Our current workaround is to use a dedicated node for the aggregate step. The downside with this solution is that load balancing is hard and we are dependent on labels or specific nodes.